# SSRS report returning no data on report server but is working in visual studio

Tags: reporting

Something really strange is happening with SSRS. I have a report which is powered by a stored proc which uses a lot of TSQL and CTE's to set variables ect... I know that there's no problem with the procedure as it runs in SQL and also runs within Visual Studio and returns a full data set. The issue I'm having is on deployment, I can't seem to get the report to return data when running it from the reporting server. The headers of the table and parameter are displayed but just no data.

I've tried the following:
- Deleting the .DATA file
- Clearing cache 
- Checking for data source errors
- Checked the report server error log 
- Rebuilt RDL and created a different report with the code

I'm clueless on this one, it's something I've never seen before.

Please help.

Much appreciated,
Thank you 
Ri

Comment: Depending on your organization, there could be a firewall issue blocking the result.  Try getting a single-table SSRS report working to determine if there is a connectivity issue.